# NINite Integration, vbs script,copy file from server and replace existing

Tags: windows-7, vbscript, deployment

Lets forget about everything besides mapping a drive and running NINite.

So here is what I have done.

I have changed the task sequence to look like this:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/194910

I have added a net use command to before the ninite script so it now looks like this:

```
net use I: \\itshares\install$ /u:crec\scollins PASSWORD /P:N
     \\itshares\install$\NINite\PRO8-1-2012\NiniteOne.exe /cachepath \\itshares\install$\NINite\Cache /select Chrome Flash "Flash (IE)" "Java 7" Malwarebytes VLC /allusers /disableshortcuts /disableautoupdate
```

I am 100% sure the script runs with my credentials.  I can map to the that bat file and run it with no problems.  But I get this error:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/194907

I am getting irritated because I keep reading its so simple but obviously I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. This question is off topic as you're talking about dealing with lots of computers in a workplace, complete with a server. I have voted to migrate this question, please don't cross vote. I will also edit the question to make it look a bit better; feel free to roll back if you don't like it

Comment: Where do you vote it gets moved to?  Serverfault..  I would not say its off topic but just not in the right place.  I thought I put at the end if this is not in the correct place please move it.

Comment: According to the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq): `and it is not about … issues specific to corporate IT support and networks'

Comment: You are absolutely right.  MODS Please move to ServerFault

Comment: It needs one more vote, then it will go there automatically

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy with an unattended file, you can just add this command to the RunSyncronous components of the OOBE pass. These will run in the background on the first login.

Comment: I added the run command line to the task sequence it starts it then stops saying the credentials are wrong. It is odd since the credentials I am using are a domain admin account and I made sure the layout is domain\user

Comment: I have edited the post with what I have done.